# Short Story Anthology: stories that were made into movies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, movie

I used to have a book that was all short stories made into movies.  I know the story for Death Race 2000 and I think The Running Man were in there.  Does anyone remember what it was called.  I would like to get it again.

Comment: Do you possible remember when the book was published as *"The Racer"*, the story Death Race was based on, was published in a few anthologies.

Comment: [One of these?](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?96327)

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35472?

Answer (score 11):

I guess it's one of these anthologies containing [Ib Melchior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ib_Melchior)'s story ["The Racer"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?96327) aka [*Death Race 2000*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Race_2000). (That story is in [a few other anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?96327), but these are the ones on the made-into-movies theme.)

[*They Came from Outer Space: 12 Classic Science Fiction Tales That Became Major Motion Pictures*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?50954) (1981) edited by [Jim Wynorski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Wynorski):

[image]

[*Reel Future:The Stories That Inspired 16 Classic Science Fiction Movies*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?201585) (1994) edited by [Forrest J. Ackerman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forrest_J_Ackerman) and [Jean Stine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Marie_Stine):

[image]

[*Science-Fiction Classics: The Stories That Morphed into Movies*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?156411) (1999) edited by [Forrest J. Ackerman](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/ackerman_forrest_j):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**You're probably thinking of [Reel Future](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?201585)**

[image: cover]

*Reel Future* is an anthology of stories on which films were made, including:

- "The Racer" (*Death Race 2000*) by Ib Melchior
- "Eight O'Clock in the Morning" (*They Live!*) by Ray Nelson
- "Who Goes There?" (*The Thing*) by John W. Campbell, Jr.

And others. Each story had a little blurb about how it came to be made into a film, and I recall there were some black & white photos from the films as well.

*The Running Man* was based on a novella by Richard Bachman (a.k.a. Stephen King), which seems to have only been published with other books by "Bachman".